# Is there a special restriction on commands executed by cron?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have a `crontab` that looks like

```
0 0 * * * pg_dump DB_NAME > /path/to/dumps/`date +%Y%m%d`.dmp
```

which works fine when I run it manually, but not when `cron` runs it. After digging through the logs, I see

```
Dec 12 00:00:01 localhost crond[17638]: (postgres) CMD (pg_dump DB_NAME > /path/to/dumps/`date +)
```

It looks like a problem with percent signs, but the `man` page doesn't even contain the percent character at all, so I thought they were alright.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to escape percent signs with a backslash:

```
0 0 * * * pg_dump DB_NAME > /path/to/dumps/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.dmp
```

From `man 5 crontab`:

> The  ‘‘sixth’’ field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to
>   be
>          run.  The entire command portion of the line, up  to  a 
>   newline  or  %
>          character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in
>   the
>          SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the 
>   command,
>          unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline
>   characters, and all data after the first % will be sent  to  the  command
>   as
>          standard  input.  There  is  no way to split a single command line
>   onto
>          multiple lines, like the shell’s trailing "\".

Comment: Right you are. I was looking at the wrong man page (just man crontab instead of man 5 crontab).

Comment: sometimes, you even need two backslashes, e.g. \\%F

Answer (score 3):

There's another characteristic problem that can affect programs run by `cron` as compared with the command line (other than the interpretation of '`%`' signs described by Robert Gamble).

That difference is in the environment.  If the program run relies on special environment variables, then it will work when you run it from the command line, with the environment you normally use, and it will likely work if you run it with `at` because that captures the environment when you create the job.  But `cron` does no special environment setting.

I habitually, therefore, configure `cron` to run scripts by absolute pathname, and that script does the environment setting that I need (adds my `$HOME/bin` directory to PATH, for example).  I even have a standardized infrastructure for this - a shell script that sets the environment and runs other programs.

```
#   @(#)$Id: crontab,v 4.2 2007/09/17 02:41:00 jleffler Exp $
#   Crontab file for Home Directory for Jonathan Leffler (JL)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Min     Hour    Day     Month   Weekday Command
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/hourly
1        1       *       *       *       /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/daily
23       1       *       *       1-5     /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/weekday
2        3       *       *       0       /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/weekly
21       3       1       *       *       /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/monthly
```

The script in `/work1/jleffler/bin/Cron` sets the environment and then runs the script of the same name in `/work1/jleffler/bin` to do the real work.  The names in the `Cron` sub-directory are actually all links to the same script.