# chpasswd is unknown command when called in cronjob?

Tags: bash, cron

I am curious about the following:

I have a bash script, which is executed once in a month through a cronjob. The following line is giving an error "unknown command" when ran through the cronjob:

```
echo $P | chpasswd
```

When I execute the bash script directly, it is working properly.

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: What is the PATH supplied to your `cron` job?  Where is `chpasswd` stored?  Since the directory where `chpasswd` is not listed in the path provided by `cron`, it fails to find it.  You get a very limited environment with `cron`; anything the least out of the ordinary means great care is required, either setting PATH more fully or specifying the absolute pathname of the commands.

Comment: How do you set `P` for `echo` to echo it?  Doesn't it set the same value each month?  Is that wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting commentary into an answer.*</sup>

What is the `PATH` supplied to your `cron` job? Where is `chpasswd` stored? Since the directory where `chpasswd` is stored is not listed in the path provided by `cron`, it fails to find it. You get a very limited environment with `cron`; running anything the least out of the ordinary means great care is required.

Either set PATH more fully in the script run by the `cron` job, or specify the absolute pathname of the commands that are not in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Incidentally, how do you set `P` for `echo` to echo it? Doesn't it set the same value each month? Is that wise?

There are numerous other questions on Stack Overflow about difficulties running commands from `cron` jobs.  Amongst others, see [Bash script not running in `cron` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812425) and [Perl script works but not via `cron`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341324) and [Is there a special restriction on commands executed by `cron`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363049), to name but three.

Comment: Thank You. My chpasswd is located @ /usr/sbin - I added the absolute path and now it is working when called via the cronjob.

P is set different every month. There are fixed parts and varying parts, which in combination are P. The varying parts are calculated in a way that only I know and thus I know about the valid password at every time.